# Input type checkbox with image

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm wondering how can I make **checkbox image** with html that I can send it with php to email. Or how can I target that image in checkbox with php?

I want that to be like small shop, that you can click on image and send it to email and ask for price.

Here is my tiny code:

```
    <form>
    <label>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hr/thumb/5/55/Avatar_2009.jpg/220px-Avatar_2009.jpg">
        <input type="checkbox" id="box">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="ask for price">

   </form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The image isn't in the checkbox. You cannot access the client side HTML using PHP.

Comment: Yes, I put that image in label that I can click on it. Do you have an idea how to make something like that? I update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another label and use `for`

**TRY THIS:**

```html
<form>
  <label for="box">

    <input type="checkbox" id="box">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hr/thumb/5/55/Avatar_2009.jpg/220px-Avatar_2009.jpg">

  </label>

<input type="submit" value="ask for price">
</form>
```

Comment: @TNX I have tested my solution and it seems to be working please test it on your end!

Comment: You can't have a label inside a label.

Comment: Ha ha. Weird...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman what?

Comment: Weird that it works for you...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I should just delete my answer right?

Comment: Yes better... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman so rude lol

Comment: LoL. No. I didn't want you to get downvotes because of an answer to a question that's totally unclear. `:)` If I were in your position, I'd delete the answer. Just my thought.

Comment: @dumbgeek thank you a lot for your answer, I tryed with this but I can't recive that image on mail :/ I target it with php like this: $image = $_POST['image']; $emailbody = "<img src='$image'>"; I add name="image" to input checkbox

Comment: @dumbgeek I'ts working thank youuu. I just add this variable to php $emailbody = "<img src=$image>"; and value for input is: value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hr/thumb/5/55/Avatar_2009.jpg/220px-Avatar_2009.jpg"

Comment: @TNX can you accept please?